# R: Conditional writing into new vector

Tags: r, return-value

I have one vector with numeric values.

```
tstat
 [1]  -1.1210000   3.5833333   1.3142857  -0.1923077  -3.0300000  -0.2000000  -6.1200000  -3.9100000  -3.6103448
[10]   0.1352113  -0.4159624  -0.4961656   1.0370899   0.9312866   0.4525845  -0.2533333   0.3772894   0.8944724
[19]   0.6288688  -1.0187899  -1.7015306  -5.3750000  -2.7166667  -0.5000000  -0.1750000   0.7500000  -1.9230769
[28]   1.6400000  -8.3300000  -0.5800000  -8.2100000 -29.1019284 -18.7434211 -10.2397004   4.4171734  -1.9033108
[37]   4.4171734   0.7322762  -2.3500000  -5.5100000  -0.6855346   0.7477273  -0.7500000  -3.0400000  -2.1900000
[46]   0.2000000   1.1650469  -1.7006965   4.4171734   4.4171734  -0.7977768   4.4171734   0.0009231   4.7000000
[55]  -3.8600000   2.9300000   4.4500000  -6.2400000  -4.6000000  -2.1200000  -5.0200000  -4.6700000  -5.8700000
[64]  -5.1200000  -2.1800000   3.0000000   3.2000000   3.4900000   3.7300000  -2.8900000  -4.3500000  -0.3400000
[73]  -0.1800000  -0.5400000  -2.3500000  -0.5700000  -1.8000000  -5.4100000  -7.7562386   2.7343035  -7.3204276
[82]   7.0203388  -4.4171734  -4.4171734   2.6200000   2.0900000  -4.3500000   3.4400000   2.2000000  -4.3100000
[91]  -2.2300000  -2.7600000 -12.9000000  -4.0000000   0.2200000  -8.0540000
```

I would like to:

```
if vector tstat has value > 1.282, then write YES in new vector B
if vector tstat has value < -1.282, then write NO in new vector B
if vector tstat has value between -1.282 and 1.282, then write NA in new vector B
```

I am trying with `match`but I could get it to work with < > signs. How can I do that?

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: I think it is a matter of nested `ifelse` but maybe some data to play with would stop the guessing and start the coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a nested `ifelse()`

```
set.seed(2)
(A <- sample(-70:70, 10))
# [1] -44  28   9 -47  59  58 -53  41  -8   2
ifelse(A > 32, "YES", ifelse(A < -32, "NO", NA))
# [1] "NO"  NA    NA    "NO"  "YES" "YES" "NO"  "YES" NA    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach, without `ifelse()`. I think this should be faster.

```
set.seed(2)
A <- sample(-70:70,10)
B <- vector()
B[A > 32] <- "YES"
B[A < -32] <- "NO" 
#[1] "NO"  NA    NA    "NO"  "YES" "YES" "NO"  "YES" NA    NA
```

With the data of your edited post, this would be:

```
B <- vector()
B[tsat > 1.282] <- "YES"
B[tsat < -1.282] <- "NO"
> B
# [1] NA    "YES" "YES" NA    "NO"  NA    "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    "NO"  "NO" 
#[23] "NO"  NA    NA    NA    "NO"  "YES" "NO"  NA    "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES" NA    "NO"  "NO"  NA    NA    NA    "NO" 
#[45] "NO"  NA    NA    "NO"  "YES" "YES" NA    "YES" NA    "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "YES"
#[67] "YES" "YES" "YES" "NO"  "NO"  NA    NA    NA    "NO"  NA    "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "YES" "YES" "NO"  "YES"
#[89] "YES" "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  "NO"  NA    "NO"
```

**data**

```
tsat <- c( -1.1210000,   3.5833333,   1.3142857,  -0.1923077,  -3.0300000,  -0.2000000,  -6.1200000,  -3.9100000,  -3.6103448,
0.1352113,  -0.4159624,  -0.4961656,   1.0370899,   0.9312866,   0.4525845,  -0.2533333,   0.3772894,   0.8944724,
0.6288688,  -1.0187899,  -1.7015306,  -5.3750000,  -2.7166667,  -0.5000000,  -0.1750000,   0.7500000,  -1.9230769,
1.6400000,  -8.3300000,  -0.5800000,  -8.2100000, -29.1019284, -18.7434211, -10.2397004,   4.4171734,  -1.9033108,
4.4171734,   0.7322762,  -2.3500000,  -5.5100000,  -0.6855346,   0.7477273,  -0.7500000,  -3.0400000,  -2.1900000,
0.2000000,   1.1650469,  -1.7006965,   4.4171734,   4.4171734,  -0.7977768,   4.4171734,   0.0009231,   4.7000000,
-3.8600000,   2.9300000,   4.4500000,  -6.2400000,  -4.6000000,  -2.1200000,  -5.0200000,  -4.6700000,  -5.8700000,
-5.1200000,  -2.1800000,   3.0000000,   3.2000000,   3.4900000,   3.7300000,  -2.8900000,  -4.3500000,  -0.3400000,
-0.1800000,  -0.5400000,  -2.3500000,  -0.5700000,  -1.8000000,  -5.4100000,  -7.7562386,   2.7343035,  -7.3204276,
7.0203388,  -4.4171734,  -4.4171734,   2.6200000,   2.0900000,  -4.3500000,   3.4400000,   2.2000000,  -4.3100000,
-2.2300000,  -2.7600000, -12.9000000,  -4.0000000,   0.2200000,  -8.0540000)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it as well, and it work perfectly! Out of curiosity, it is possibile with this method to choose something rather than "NA" for the values that doesn't belong to the conditional writing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this can be done. For instance `B[abs(tsat) < 0.5] <- "Near zero"` should work as an additional conditon. Alternatively, you could replace the `NA`s at the end with something like  `B[is.na(B)] <- "Maybe"`.

Comment: Tried both way and of course they both works but, in my noob opinion (for what it matters) `B[is.na(B)] <- "Maybe"` is more intuitive and I will remember this one for the future. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. I also like the other answers, so I think that you have a number of good choices now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another one liner: use `cut` to bin the data, then plug that into a lookup table:

```
B <- c("NO", NA, "YES")[cut(tstat, c(-Inf, -1.28, 1.28, Inf), labels=FALSE)]
```

Edit: actually, use `findInterval`, it's faster and easier to read:

```
B <- c("NO", NA, "YES")[findInterval(tstat, c(-Inf, -1.28, 1.28, Inf))]
```